# Run Javascript code in my website like Stackoverflow

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

On my website, I have some Javascript code that I need to run right on my site.
For example, with this code snippet:

```
console.log("Hello World")
```

I have a button "Run code snippet". What I want to do is: When I click on the button, the code gets executed right on my web. Just like this functionality on Stackoverflow:
[image]

How can I do it ? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: "Sandbox" is the key word you're looking for.

Comment: Check out https://tour.rubico.land/. It's a pretty minimal website with runnable code examples like you want. The source is available on [github](https://github.com/a-synchronous/tour.rubico.land)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple demonstration of what you can start with. In general, this is not considered safe and for this to be production-ready, you will have to think about isolating the execution context seriously.

I just wanted to provide you an entry point. You can execute your JS here.

```js
function runCode() {

    var console = {

       log:  function (val) {
          let paragraph = document.getElementById("console");
          let text = document.createTextNode(val);
          
          paragraph.appendChild(text);
          paragraph.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
       }
    }

 
    var code = document.getElementById('myjs').value;
 
 
  eval(code);
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myjs" style="width: 320px; height: 120px">
   //Sample code
   function add(a, b) {
      return a + b;
   }

   let c = add(9, 1);
   
   console.log('9 + 1 = ' + c);
   
</textarea>


<input type="button" value = "Run" onClick="runCode()">

<p id="console"></p>
```